# Can I create a tibble with 1 row and 11 columns in R from a data frame with 0 rows and 0 columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, twitter, tibble

I have imported some Twitter data which gives me a list with tibbles for every user. Each tibble has 11 columns and various number of rows depending on how many lists a Twitter user has.
If a Twitter user has no lists, it is listed as a data frame with 0 rows and 0 columns (see [3] in the picture). I don't want to delete such entries but keep them as a user with no lists.

[image]

Hence, I'm thinking whether I can create a tibble with 11 columns and 1 row where each cell contains a "99".

How do I change a data frame within a list to a tibble?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try :

```
#get index of dataframes that has 0 columns
inds <- lengths(list_data_outlier) == 0
#get column names from other dataframe which is not empty
cols <- names(list_data_outlier[[which.max(!inds)]])
#create an empty dataframe with data as 99 and 1 row
empty_df <- data.frame(matrix(99, nrow = 1, ncol = length(cols), 
                       dimnames = list(NULL, cols)))
#replace the dataframes with 0 columns with empty_df
list_data_outlier[inds] <- replicate(sum(inds), empty_df, simplify = FALSE)
```

Comment: This is very helpful! Thanks a lot. Is there any way I can create tibbles instead of dataframes?

Comment: Use `empty_df <- tibble(matrix(99, nrow = 1, ncol = length(cols), dimnames = list(NULL, cols)))`

Comment: Thanks! That gave me a tibble with 1 row and 1 column. I tried it in 2 steps which worked:
`empty_df <- data.frame(matrix(99, nrow = 1, ncol = length(cols), 
                              dimnames = list(NULL, cols)))
empty_df <- tibble(empty_df)`

Comment: Please excuse that I keep bothering you, but do you also have an idea how I can change the column type from double to character/integer/logical? Thanks!

Comment: Instead of creating dataframe with 99 as value you can use the 1st row as `empty_df` i.e `empty_df <- list_data_outlier[[which.max(!inds)]][1, ]` but this will repeat the 1st row in each empty dataframe. You might want to ask a new question regarding this.

Comment: Ah, I see. I think this might work best for now. It's not ideal to have the first rows in the empty dataframes but I'm changing the entire list into one dataframe and will be able to adjust it there. Thanks again so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again, @Ronak Shah!
This worked well:

```
inds <- lengths(list_data_outlier) == 0
empty_df <- list_data_outlier[[which.max(!inds)]][1, ]
list_data_outlier[inds] <- replicate(sum(inds), empty_df, simplify = FALSE)
```

But instead of choosing the first row and hence, having wrong data in the DF, I used the 50th row:

```
empty_df <- list_data_outlier[[which.max(!inds)]][50, ]
```

The number is depending on the number of entries nrows + 1.
That way you'll get a tibble with 1 row and the same number and types of columns as in the rest of your list but instead of filling it with "wrong" data it's filled with NAs which is what I needed to continue with my analysis.

[image]